# Is there a way to clone a computer, create a duplicate (physical or virtual) and have the changes made on one instantly replicate to the other?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-backup

I guess what I'm looking for is a continuous data protection solution, but one that also has constant availability.  So if one machine or the other were to fail for whatever reason, there wouldn't be any recovery time, and the other machine could be used in the same manner as the original, immediately, with no necessary recovery time. Does such a configuration exist? If not, what's the best that I can do?

Comment: Terminal server and diskless workstations?

Comment: @Akina, how would that work if the Terminal Server fails?

Comment: @StarCat TS must be fail-safe. A lot of TSs with load balancing at least.